# Error encountered while using the SQL Module

Tags: python, sql

I am attempting to create a table using SQL and enter some values

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect("Classes.db")
c = conn.cursor()
score1 = 5
score2 = 5
score3 = 5
name = ("Brad")
Class = 2
def tableCreate():
    c.execute(("CREATE TABLE Class{}(Name TEXT, Score1 INT,Score2 INT, Score3 INT)").format(Class))
def dataEntry():
    c.execute(("INSERT INTO Class{} (Name,Score1,Score2,Score3) VALUES (?,?,?,?)").format(Class),
    (name,score1,score2,score3).format(Class))
    conn.commit()
```

I encounter this error when running dataEntry()

```
line 13, in dataEntry
    (name,score1,score2,score3).format(Class))
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'format'
```

Comment: Please don't change your question almost entirely. If you have a *different* question, create a new post.

Comment: If you wanted to print the output, you'd have to add another query; do a `c.execute('SELECT ...')`, then loop over the cursor to fetch rows (each a tuple) and print that.

Comment: Changing your question makes any answers invalid; you'll just have to be patient and do some more research in the meantime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call format *only on the query string*, not on the parameters tuple:

```
c.execute(
    "INSERT INTO Class{} (Name,Score1,Score2,Score3) VALUES (?,?,?,?)".format(Class),
    (name,score1,score2,score3))
```

Perhaps the parentheses around the string confused you; those were redundant and I removed them too.